# Is it okay to say quit a place?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Once I said:

> Just, quit the house!

Someone told me it's just not okay to say that. I'd better use "leave". Now, today, I saw it on a show that someone was saying:

> We should quit this place.

And I thought to myself about this... So, using "leave" is okay but is it okay to use this same structure with "quit"?

Comment: "quit this" as in "give up on this" is ok (where that makes sense). Doesn't work with "the" however. "Quit **this** house" would be ok.

Comment: If you said: **Just quit the house**, everybody would know what you meant. If you were writing a book in which characters spoke like that, it would fit perfectly. If you were composing an essay in an English exam,  prefer **leave** to **quit**. It's a question of context rather than grammar.  In my experience, **quit** is most often used in front of habits such as smoking and drinking to mean **give up** (for a while at least).

Comment: @Ronald Sole, understood! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, people use "leave" when they go away from where they live.
But, It is O.k using "quit" instead of "leave". According to the Oxford,
the definition of "quit" is to leave the place where you live.

Comment: I would definitely **not** say it's okay for an English learner to use "quit" instead of "leave." It's archaic usage that would probably draw some funny looks.

Comment: @bak1936 So is it only used for the place that you live in? `Quit the house` can't just be all about a general house? Also, I don't think we can use it with `home`, right?

Comment: @JOUA  reference ; https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/quit?q=quit  (number 3)